# Why is keydown via addEventListener not having any effect on my js (webGL) program?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

I am writing a WebGL javascript program and need to determine when the SHIFT key has been pressed. My mouse listeners of the same format are working fine, but

```
canvas.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    console.log("A");
});
```

neither causes an error nor logs "A" to the console as it should when I press keys inside the canvas. It seems to simply have no effect. Why might this be and what must I change to get the response I am after?

Comment: instead of `canvas` try `window`

Comment: @gaitat That did the trick! Thank you so much!